# Google Apps Script Get Textbox Value Insert into Database

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, google-apps-script

Can someone please help me figure out how to get the value of a textbox to write to a MS SQL database? I have the database connection working PERFECTLY, now I just need to determine how to **grab the value of the textbox and write it to the database** with Google Apps Script.

Right now the code below will only insert the word TEXT to the database and not the value of the textbox.

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  var panel = app.createAbsolutePanel();
  var label = app.createLabel('Test Textbox');
  var text = app.createTextBox();
  var submit = app.createButton('Submit');

  panel.add(label);
  panel.add(text);
  panel.add(submit);

  app.add(panel);

  // Handlers
  var handler = app.createServerClickHandler('write');
  handler.addCallbackElement(panel);
  submit.addClickHandler(handler);

  return app;
} 

// submit text to database
function write(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var text = e.parameter.text;

  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://IPAddress:1433;" +
   "databaseName=name;userusername;password=password;");

  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  var sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_Student (studentFName) VALUES ('text')";
  var count = stmt.executeUpdate(sql,1)//pass in any integer to get auto incremented IDs back

  // check to see any auto generated keys come back. that is optional. 
  var rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
  while(rs.next()) {
    Logger.log(rs.getString(1));
  }

  rs.close();
  stmt.close();
  conn.close();    

  return app.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the value of the textbox passed in, you need to create a name for the textbox:

Modify `var text = app.createTextBox();` to `var text = app.createTextBox().setName('mytb');`.

Then, in your handler function, you can retrieve this by `var text = e.parameter.mytb;`.

Also, I think you are just inserting literal word 'text' into your db. Instead, try creating the string with the text variable like this:

`var sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_Student (studentFName) VALUES ("+text+")";`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I did the changes and now receive this error message:  Error encountered: Invalid column name 'Test1'. When I attempted to submit in the texbox the words Test1. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

The code that worked:

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  var panel = app.createAbsolutePanel();
  var label = app.createLabel('Test Textbox');
  var text = app.createTextBox().setName('mytb').setId('mytb');
  var submit = app.createButton('Submit');

  panel.add(label);
  panel.add(text);
  panel.add(submit);

  app.add(panel);

  // Handlers
  var handler = app.createServerClickHandler('write');
  handler.addCallbackElement(text);
  submit.addClickHandler(handler);

  return app;
}  

// submit text to database
function write(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var textbox = app.getElementById('mytb');
  var text = e.parameter.mytb;

  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://IPAddress;" +
   "databaseName=database;user=user;password=password;");

  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  var sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_Student (studentFName) VALUES ('"+text+"')";
  var count = stmt.executeUpdate(sql,1)//pass in any integer to get auto incremented IDs back

  // check to see any auto generated keys come back. that is optional. 
  var rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
  while(rs.next()) {
    Logger.log(rs.getString(1));
  }

  rs.close();
  stmt.close();
  conn.close();

  return app.close();
}
```