# How to take a text field and set it as the description

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am working in google Apps Scripts, specifically with Google Drive. I am trying to make an application that when the user types in text into the text field, the program takes the text and sets its description using setDescription(). Everything is working fine, i just cannot figure out how to take whatever text the user enters and set it as the description.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For example, I want to have an onClick which calls this method that I dont know how to make which takes in the field from this text box and uses what's in the text box to setDescription() if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

**First get the value of input**

Example code from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14816195/get-textbox-value-from-google-apps-script):

```
var textbox = app.createTextBox().setName("textboxName");
var buttonHandler = app.createServerHandler("updateLabelText").addCallbackElement(textbox);
var button = app.createButton("Click me").addClickHandler(buttonHandler);
var label = app.createLabel().setId("label");
Then in your function:

function updateLabelText(e) {
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
app.getElementById("label").setText(e.parameter.textboxName);
return app;
}
```

**[Assign a Simple Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)**

- `doGet(e)` runs when a user visits a web app or a program sends an HTTP GET request to a web app.
- `doPost(e)` runs when a program sends an HTTP POST request to a web app.

**[Set Text as Description](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setdescriptiondescription)**

// Trash every untitled spreadsheet that hasn't been updated in a week.
var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName('Untitled spreadsheet');
files.setDescription(description)

Comment: Thanks so much, this is perfect. The next issues I am running into is that I want to take the description from a variable rather than having it as a direct string. I know the class says that it only takes a string but is there a way to assign specifically a string variable to the textbox so that I can set the description to whatever they type in. Also, I know there is a getId in the files class, is there a way to use this to get the file id of every document that uses this app rather than having to type in the name of the doc in the DriveApp.getFilesByName()? Thanks so much, I appreciate it!

Comment: What do you mean by assigning specifically a string variable to the textbox?  I think if you set the `var description = app.getElementById("label").setText(e.parameter.textboxName);` it would be enough to make it a dynamic variable that will get the description the user type. For the problem regarding the file you can use the Class DriveApp `getFiles()` to create a dropdown list. Follow the sample in the [document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator) and add `file.getFileById(id)`. I hoep this helps